# Check the button event handler it is not performing the desired function?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class product_entry : System.Web.UI.Page
{
int count;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        tr.Attributes.Add("class", "tabrow");

        for (j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();

            if (j == 0)
            {
                tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<Button class=remove type=button>-</button>"));
            }
            if (j == 1)
            {
                tc.Attributes.Add("class", "sno");
            }
            if (j == 2 || j == 3 || j == 4 || j == 5 || j == 6 || j == 7 || j == 8)
            {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.Style["width"] = "98%";
                tc.Controls.Add(tb);
            }
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);
        }
        Table1.Controls.Add(tr);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
    {
        TextBox aa = (TextBox)Pnl.FindControl("textbox" + i + j);
        Response.Write(aa.Text);
    }
}
}
}
```

I am trying to get the values of text box which I generated dynamically on page load and cloned them using jquery....

Every text box has a unique id in form of a matrix for eg textboxes of row one have ids textbox11,textbox12,textbox13,textbox14 etc for row two textbox21,textbox22,textbox23........

Is there any way to get the values..
also the loop int button event handler is not performing its task

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ TextBox aa = (TextBox)Pnl.FindControl("textbox22"); 
Label2.Text = aa.Text;}
```

I tried this to check the result but it gives error

Comment: you havent set any id to textbox in page_load

Comment: i have used jquery to seet the id of the text boxes.each text box has a uniqueid like texttbox11,textbox12etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your dynamic textbox in `Page_PreInit` method

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "textBox";
        tb.Text = "";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
```

Comment: the text boxes are cloned again and again using jquery.so all the text boxes are not created at the time of pageload

Comment: You might then need to give name to those textboxes and retrieve its value using Request["nameOftxtBox"]